# Git over Bitvise SSH produces git-upload-pack error

Tags: ssh, git

I have been trying to set up a simple SSH server on my PC to use with Git. The idea is to have a git repo on my PC and push any work I do from my laptop when outside. Both machines run Windows 8.

I tried a couple of SSH server solutions, but I finally decided to go with Bitvise SSH server. I can SSH  normally from my laptop using public key authentication.

When I try to use Git though, I get an error `git-upload-pack: command not found`. I seached around and ended up on a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/225315/284263) from stack overflow which basically said that the PATH might no be properly set for non-logic users.

I actually executed the command [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17221/matt-curtis) said, and it turns out that c\git\bin is not part of the PATH, even though I have set it as a system variable. As far as I can see, editing the system enviornmental variables in Windows does not affect this PATH. Any ideas how I need to set this properly?

Bitvise's settings for the virtual user group I use are the following:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Today, I've had the same experience. I was trying to setup a Git server on Windows 7, with the Bitvise SSH server. After having setup the SSH server and installing Git, when I tried to pull from the origin, I received `git-upload-pack: command not found` and when trying to push to the origin I received `git-receive-pack: command not found`.

Obviously, this is server side problem. The server cannot execute `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack`. What you will need to do:

To use these Git commands, you should add them to your PATH variable. Follow these steps:

1. Find the path to your Git install directory (On my machine it's `C:\Installs\Git`)
2. On your desktop/start menu: right-click `My Computer` > `Properties`
3. Click `Advanced System settings`
4. Open the tab `Advanced`
5. Click the button `Environment variables`
6. Under `System variables` find `Path` and click `Edit...`
7. Append `;C:\Installs\Git\libexec\git-core` in the lower box.
8. Click OK, OK, OK, and close everything.

Now, `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` is available in the command line. This is how I fixed this exact problem. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to use Git though, I get an error git-upload-pack: command not found. I seached around and ended up on a post from stack overflow which basically said that the PATH might no be properly set for non-logic users.

This PATH is not the PATH in the system environment. It's the path for user@sshserver.

You can use `ls` or `dir` which depend on what terminal you provide for the ssh client to find The PATH for user@sshserver.

And you need to change the permission for the user on that PATH on server side. You can also refer this [link](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/others/tips/how-to-setup-git-server-using-bitvise-ssh/).